# Node Version Manager (NVM) npm installing modules to common folder

Tags: node.js

I've installed NVM for node.js using the instructions from this post:

http://www.backdrifter.com/2011/02/18/using-nvm-and-npm-to-manage-node-js/

When I switch between node versions and then use npm to install a module, all the modules are placed in the same 'node_modules' folder (~/node_modules/) instead of in the 'node_modules' directory specific to that version of node?

Any idea on how to remedy this?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Based on the comments from https://github.com/creationix/nvm/pull/97:

> When installing packages with npm using the global switch -g the
>   package ends up in the proper directory (i.e.
>   .nvm/$VERSION/lib/node_modules), however node is unable to require it
>   since it somehow isn't searching on it's prefix.

So using `npm install -g xxxxx` will put the modules in the correct location for NVM but if you try to `require` one of them node can't find the module. I am still playing around with this and will update if I find a solution.

**Update**

Where does NPM put node_modules? (see https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders)

- Local install (default): puts stuff in ./node_modules of the current package root.
- Global install (with -g): puts stuff in /usr/local or wherever node is installed.
- Install it locally if you're going to `require()` it.
- Install it globally if you're going to run it on the command line.
- If you need both, then install it in both places, or use `npm link`.

So what I did was run `npm init` (see http://npmjs.org/doc/init.html) in my projects root dir which generated package.json. Now when I run `npm install xxxxx` it creates a node_modules dir in my project folder (which I add to my .gitignore). This works for modules that I require in my code.

For commands such as CoffeeScript I install with `npm install -g coffee-script` which puts it in the correct directory (.nvm/$VERSION/lib/node_modules). While I can't require these modules (npm link should solve this problem) I can run the commands - i.e. `coffee`.

Answer (score 1):

I just installed express globally (-g) and was having problem when require("express"). Just like Jesse Vogt said I just reinstalled express but this time without the -g just like this: "sudo npm install express" and now is working perfectly!

Comment: To be honest with you; I do not know, I am pretty newbie with this. However, surfing on the web that Jesse left (https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-locally) I found the following:

"If you want to depend on the package from your own module using something like Node's require, then you want to install locally..."

I do not understand pretty well the difference but for sure if you need to use require() to run a server you shall make the installation locally (w/o the -g), because that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For latest nvm window version `1.1.7`. 
Package was installed and placed into the respective nodejs version.

```
nvm use 16.8.0
npm install truffle
```

[image]

```
nvm use 16.7.0
npm install mysql
```

[image]