# node.js, Error: Cannot find module 'express'

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to Node.js, try to learn express to build my first web application. I got stuck on my very first sample code and need some help to get it running.  Before I post this question, I did search on stack overflow, found some similar questions but still could not fix it.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
```

I am using **mac os 10.8.2**.  I have Node.js installed using `nvm`.

```
node.js: 0.8.20 path to node:    /Users/feelexit/nvm/v0.8.20/bin/node
path to express: /Users/feelexit/nvm/node_modules/express
```

here's my sample code: this file locates at:

**/Users/feelexit/WebstormProjects/learnnode/node_modules/index.js**

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('welcome to express');
});
app.listen(3000);
```

when I try to run this command `node index.js` I get following error message, please help me to fix it.

Thank you.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/feelexit/WebstormProjects/learnnode/node_modules/index.js:1:81)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:492:10)
feelexits-Mac:node_modules feelexit$
```

**Update to answer chovy's question:**

```
feelexits-Mac:~ feelexit$ npm install
npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/feelexit/package.json'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Darwin 12.2.0
npm ERR! command "/Users/feelexit/nvm/v0.8.20/bin/node" "/Users/feelexit/nvm/v0.8.20/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/feelexit
npm ERR! node -v v0.8.20
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.11
npm ERR! path /Users/feelexit/package.json
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/feelexit/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: May be this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133784/node-version-manager-nvm-npm-installing-modules-to-common-folder

Comment: Did you type `npm install`

Comment: Are you certain that the express library is in your "node_modules" folder? You may also want to try moving your _index.js_ file up one directory to "/Users/feelexit/WebstormProjects/learnnode/" and leave the node_modules folder alone.

Comment: Please post your `package.json` file. That will help in debugging the problem.

Comment: @chovy, I use npm install express to install express. what does only "npm install" do ?

Comment: @Akhil Raina, where is the package.json file?

Comment: @Default, yes, it is in the node_modules folder. I moved it one direotry up to  "/Users/feelexit/WebstormProjects/learnnode/", still same error.

Comment: Does your express library have a _package.json_ file in the express/ directory (express/package.json)? Also, I just noticed that you have your express module located in a different directory than your project. That is probably the problem since you are trying to `require()` it locally. Move your express module from _/Users/feelexit/nvm/node_modules/express_ to _/Users/feelexit/WebstormProjects/learnnode/node_modules/express_ and let me know if that solves your problem. [This info](https://npmjs.org/doc/folders.html) can give you more detail about node_module file structures.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js Error: Cannot find module express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17162308/node-js-error-cannot-find-module-express)

Comment: Make sure your `package.json` file has all the required libraries before `npm install` I had installed them via the command line previously without the `--save` and they were not in the `package.json` file, so basically my setup was missing dependencies.

Answer (score 253):

It says

```
Cannot find module 'express'
```

Do you have express installed? If not then run this.

```
npm install express
```

and run your program again.

Comment: This does not fix the problem in my case. `npm install express` shows this error `npm ERR! Error: UNKNOWN, symlink '../express/bin/express'`. Seems to be a deeper issue.

Comment: Use sudo if you have not fixed your directory permissions for npm. In any case, "sudo npm install" is a better option.

Comment: symlink Errors often occur, if you installed things globally and, yeah, the symlink broke. Try `npm link` to re-create the respective linking...

Comment: @Sliq I tried with your solution but i can't solve my problem can you help me ?

Comment: Don't overlook "And run your program again." In my case i had to restart the process in my `process manager`. It didn't restart by itself.

Comment: Prolly too late! But you shall redo npm install, it will fetch all the missing dependency at once.

Comment: But surely one should be able to run a bundle without dependencies post build, no?

Answer (score 54):

After you do express in your terminal, then do

```
npm install
```

To install all the dependencies.

Then you can do node app to run the server.

Comment: You should point out that this requires a package list file ie .json.. And this is not always the case.

Comment: @VjyV in the same directory you have your .js node file. But it should have the package.json file in the directory so that it can install the required dependencies.

Answer (score 40):

```
npm install --save express
```

This worked for me. Just run express.js installation again.

Answer (score 39):

Check if you have installed `express` module. If not, use this command:

```
npm install express
```

and if your `node_modules` directory is in another place, set `NODE_PATH` envirnment variable:

```
set NODE_PATH=your\directory\to\node_modules;%NODE_PATH%
```

Comment: **This** is the right answer, to everyone posting these `CTRL+C / CTRL+V` `npm install` answers: do you really think anyone would try to run something without  checking if its installed first? Seriously...

Comment: Just adding a minor detail: You need to run the install express command in the directory of your application and **not** in your Node.js installation folder or the npm-folder in AppData. Because that's the mistake I made, because I thought it was some kind of SDK-add-on.

Answer (score 14):

npm install from within your app directory will fix the issue as it will install everything required

Answer (score 8):

Unless you set **Node_PATH**, the only other option is to install express in the app directory, like `npm install express --save`.
Express may already be installed but `node` cannot find it for some reason

Comment: This one worked for me, better execute the install command in same directory as your .js files are. Also you may run command " npm init " to create package.json file to avoid further problems.

Answer (score 5):

Digging up an old thread here BUT I had this same error and I resolved by navigating to the directory my NodeApp resides in and running `npm install -d`

Comment: Not sure why or how it matters but this installs it in your devdependencies: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Comment: @GuyLowe `-d` is debug for npm, `-D` is dev dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes there are error while installing the node modules
Try this:

1. Delete node_modules
2. npm install

Answer (score 3):

You have your express module located in a different directory than your project. That is probably the problem since you are trying to `require()` it locally. Try moving your express module from */Users/feelexit/nvm/node_modules/express* to */Users/feelexit/WebstormProjects/learnnode/node_modules/express*. [This info](https://npmjs.org/doc/folders.html) can give you more detail about node_module file structures.

Answer (score 3):

if youre main file is located at `/Users/feelexit/WebstormProjects/learnnode/node_modules/index.js` then express needs to be located
at `/Users/feelexit/WebstormProjects/learnnode/node_modules/node_modules` as node always looks for modules in `./node_modules` (and its internal folder)
when the path dont start with `./` or `/` ([more info here](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_file_modules))

i think you miss placed youre main file in the module folder

Answer (score 3):

for this scenario run npm install express command using your cmd prompt for the respective folder where you want to run the program.
Example I want to run the express module program server.js in F:\nodeSample. So run "npm install express" in that particular folder then run server.js

Answer (score 1):

Run `npm install express body-parser cookie-parser multer --save` command in the same directory with your source code nodejs file to resolve this issue.
P/s: check your directory after run command to understand more!

Answer (score 1):

In rare cases, npm cache may get corrupt.  For me, what worked was:

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Generally, the package manager will detect corruption and refetch on its own so this is not usually necessary.  However, in my case Windows 10 crashed a few times and I suspect this may have been during a fetch operation.  Hope it helps someone!

More information: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/cache

Comment: Thanks! In my case node get corrupt after installing BigSur. Cache clean worked!

Answer (score 1):

On Debian the easiest way is to issue as root

```
apt install node-express
```

Answer (score 0):

`npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/feelexit/package.json'`

This happens due to missing permissions or unlinked files while npm was working.

Meaning, that executing `npm` as this user doesn't have enough rights to read/write from a file, in this case package.json.

try adding `sudo` before the entire command - it should resolve.

`$ sudo npm install -g express`
`$ Password:*******`

Password would be your admin password of your mac.

`-g` flag will install this module (express) in the global context of node - meaning node will/should recognize `express` module from within any js file without having to provide a full path to the module in use.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My issue was that I have to change to the Node.js project directory on the command line before installing express.

```
cd /Users/feelexit/WebstormProjects/learnnode/node_modules/
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that this is coursework from Colt Steele's Web Development course... I was looking for the same answer as to why I ended up with that error too.. Colt doesn't say so but you take the node_module folder and move into the new folder you're working in... that's what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
D:\learn\Node.js\node app.js
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'body-parser'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

Sometimes version not match with package.json
Fixed the problem by checking the package.json then use the following commands:
npm install body-parser@1.13.2
it resolved for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've came across a similar problem and in the end it was a matter of some old dependencies that were messing up my Heroku server.

While at my project's folder I've run:

```
npm uninstall
npm install
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
npm install
```

If you're specifically looking for just express

```
npm install --save express
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was trying to run the same as you but using nodemon.
The error was the same but the problem was because  on my package.json I added app.js instead of just app

"script" : {
"dev": "nodemon app"
}

Answer (score 0):

This happens when there is an existing image that the user needs to upgrade.
Adding a volume in the statement that will create the new container is not enough.   That is because what is in the local will overwrite evearything in the new container being created.  It is not necessarily desireable to add express/node_nodules to the local.

The easy solution is to add a second, anonymous, volume to the statement that will create the new container and have it indicate which directory in the container is to be preserved.

Answer (score 0):

if

```
npm install express
```

gives error in that case edit package.json file and add following line in it

```
"dependencies":{"express":"^4.17.1"}
```

after that run command

```
npm install
```

hope that solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when trying to `ng serve` an angular application. Since this application didn't depend on the express package at any point, I cloud solve the problem by deleting the `node_modules` folder aswell as the `package-lock.json` file.