# Node.js Error: Cannot find module express

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I wrote my first node.js app, but it can't find express library:

```
C:\ChatServer\Server>node server.js

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'express'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ChatServer\Server\server.js:6:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\ChatServer\Server\server.js:25:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

But express is intalled (with `-g` key):

```
C:\ChatServer\Server>npm install -g express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/express
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.7.11
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/0.6.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/0.3.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/range-parser/0.0.4
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/connect/2.7.11
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander/0.6.1
npm WARN package.json range-parser@0.0.4 No repository field.
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffer-crc32/0.2.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/fresh/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/methods/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie-signature/1.0.1
npm WARN package.json methods@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json methods@0.0.1 No readme data.
npm WARN package.json fresh@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json send@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json cookie-signature@1.0.1 No repository field.
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.6
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.14
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime/1.2.6
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/bytes/0.2.0
npm WARN package.json bytes@0.2.0 No repository field.
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pause/0.0.1
npm WARN package.json pause@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable/1.0.14
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/qs/0.6.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/send/0.1.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cookie/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mime
C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Roaming\npm\express -> C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express\bin\express
npm WARN package.json policyfile@0.0.4 'repositories' (plural) Not supported.
npm WARN package.json Please pick one as the 'repository' field
npm WARN package.json assert-plus@0.1.2 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ctype@0.5.2 No repository field.
express@3.2.6 C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express
├── methods@0.0.1
├── fresh@0.1.0
├── range-parser@0.0.4
├── cookie-signature@1.0.1
├── buffer-crc32@0.2.1
├── cookie@0.1.0
├── debug@0.7.2
├── commander@0.6.1
├── mkdirp@0.3.4
├── send@0.1.0 (mime@1.2.6)
└── connect@2.7.11 (pause@0.0.1, qs@0.6.5, bytes@0.2.0, cookie@0.0.5, formidable@1.0.14, send@0.1.1)
```

Some information:

```
C:\ChatServer\Server>npm --version
1.2.24

C:\ChatServer\Server>node --version
v0.10.9

C:\ChatServer\Server>npm --version
1.2.24

C:\ChatServer\Server>npm ls -g installed express
npm WARN package.json cookie-signature@1.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json fresh@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json methods@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json range-parser@0.0.4 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json send@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json policyfile@0.0.4 'repositories' (plural) Not supported.
npm WARN package.json Please pick one as the 'repository' field
npm WARN package.json bytes@0.2.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json pause@0.0.1 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json assert-plus@0.1.2 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json ctype@0.5.2 No repository field.
C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── express@3.2.6


C:\ChatServer\Server>npm ls installed express
C:\ChatServer\Server
└── (empty)
```

How can I solve this problem? (**MUST** I install it without `-g`?)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NodeJS - Unable to import global modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7970793/nodejs-unable-to-import-global-modules)

Comment: possible duplicate of [NodeJS - How to resolve "Cannot find module" error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9023672/nodejs-how-to-resolve-cannot-find-module-error)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [node.js, Error: Cannot find module 'express'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949118/node-js-error-cannot-find-module-express)

Answer (score 320, accepted):

You need to install Express locally into the context of your application (`node_modules` folder):

```
$ npm install express
```

The reason for this is that applications always look in their local context for any dependencies. The global installation is only for setting up system-wide available binaries, such as unit test runners or bootstrappers or things like that.

With Express, when you install it globally, you get an `express` binary that can bootstrap an application for you. For more information, type

```
$ express --help
```

So, to answer your final question: *YES*, you need to install it without `-g`.

Comment: This helped me too. I had `winston` installed globally, which worked for some reason when starting my app as a normal user, but when starting my app and a system init script it wouldn't work. I fixed it by installing winston locally in the app directory (and adding it to package.json).

Comment: you can link a global installed dependency by cd to your project root directory and then use "npm link <some dependency name>"

Comment: **npm install** after you've created your app. It'll install all dependencies.

Comment: Thanks this really helped. Going to node_modules folder and than installing express solved my problem

Comment: @Golo Roden Accoding your answer i tried with your solution but it's throwing error  : ' npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\VV\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache
\express\4.14.0\package.tgz
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "express"

Comment: in project directory
    **rm -rf node_modules/**
    then **npm install**

Comment: and then install all the libraries you need to install

Answer (score 23):

For me it worked when installed express locally with --save option as follow:

```
$ npm install express --save
```

Answer (score 13):

Check if you are not install `express` module, use this command:

```
 npm install express
```

and if your `node_modules` directory is in another place, set `NODE_PATH` envirnment variable:

```
 set NODE_PATH=your\directory\to\node_modules;%NODE_PATH%
```

Comment: In Windows 10 after the npm install express, it cannot automatically added to node path, you need to manually add the node modules to it.

Answer (score 5):

Golo have explain well the solution, but I might add a clarification:
sometimes node modules are installed in

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

and when you launch node blabla.js modules are searched in

```
/lib
```

So a solution is to create a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ /lib/node_modules
```

Comment: easier way -> npm link <module>

Answer (score 5):

Given you have installed *node* on your system, install Express locally for your project using the following for Windows:

```
npm install express
```

**or**

```
npm install express --save
```

You might give it global access by using:

```
npm install -g express --save
```

Answer (score 4):

In your case your `express` module is installed at `C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\express`, but you need to get this module in to your project directory. So you should copy the file the `express` module folders from `C:\Users\Dmitry\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\` to your project directory as : `C:\ChatServer\Server\node_modules`. If you do not have a folder named 'node_modules' in your project folder, then create it first and paste those files into this folder. This method worked for me on my windows pc. Restart your node server and once again run the command node `C:\ChatServer\Server>node server.js`. It should work now !!!!

Comment: Worked on windows 10 too!

Answer (score 3):

On Ubuntu-based OS you can try

```
sudo apt-get install node-express
```

its working for me on Mint

Answer (score 3):

I had this error in vscode, although the modules where installed. I am using typescript and express. In the `server.ts` files all the imports had red squiggly underlines. It turns out I had a faulty `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs", // Previously this value was `es6`
        "target": "es6",
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "baseUrl": "public",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "jsx": "react",
        "strict": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "allowJs": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "build"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error following the example on this book: "Kubernetes Up & Running".
I see many answers suggesting to install *express* "by hand" but I'm not convinced is the best solution.
Because we are using *package.json* (I can see it in the logs) and the right way to build the app is running `npm install`, I added the *express* dependency in the **package.json** file.

```
 "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
}
```

I get the current version with `npm search express`.

Answer (score 1):

create one folder in your harddisk e.g sample1 and go to command prompt type :cd and gives the path of sample1 folder  and then install all modules...

> npm install express
>
> npm install jade
>
> npm install socket.io

and then whatever you are creating application save in sample1 folder

try it...

Answer (score 1):

go to your application directory and install the express module using the below command
**npm install express --save**
then list the all install module using the below command
**npm ls**
you will see all the locally install modules.

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem. I had express installed globally at /usr/local/bin/. When I do 'npm install', express was not created in node_modules of local directory.

1. Check if you have file name .npmrc in your $HOME
2. If it has 'global = true', change to 'global = false'
3. Now do 'npm install' in application directory. More likely, you should get all package dependent modules installed in node_modules (local) within application directory.

Answer (score 0):

- sudo brew uninstall node
- brew update
- brew upgrade
- brew cleanup
- brew install node
- sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local
- brew link --overwrite node
- sudo brew postinstall node

This worked for me on **MacOS X Sierra**

Answer (score 0):

I'm not proud sharing this, but in my case I had:

```
 require('express.handlebars')

 //and the correct form is:
 require('express-handlebars'); //Use dash instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

1.first check if express is install at correct location.
2. npm install express (run this command).
3. express will save under your "node_modules" folder