# Error: Cannot find module 'mkdirp'

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, installation, npm, recovery

while i trying to run a nodeJS file am getting following error in my Ubuntu machine

```
node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Cannot find module 'mkdirp'
    at Function._resolveFilename (module.js:332:11)
    at Function._load (module.js:279:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home//dev/ation/siya/common.js:7:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
```

so i tried  `npm install mkdirp`

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: mkdirp
npm ERR!     at /home/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/home/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/home/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/home//local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic
npm ERR! command "node" "/home/local/bin/npm" "install" "mkdirp"
npm ERR! cwd /home/dev/tst_tion/servrs/sc
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: mkdirp
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ushusadmin/dev/test_automation/servers/scriptAgentServer/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

How can i solve this issue

npm debug.log file

```
info it worked if it ends with ok
verbose cli [ 'node', '/home/ushusadmin/local/bin/npm', 'install', 'mkdirp' ]
info using npm@1.1.4
info using node@v0.6.12
verbose config file /home/ushusadmin/.npmrc
verbose config file /home/ushusadmin/local/etc/npmrc
verbose config file /home/ushusadmin/local/lib/node_modules/npm/npmrc
verbose caching /home/ushusadmin/dev/test_automation/servers/scriptAgentServer/node_modules/node-schedule/package.json
verbose caching /home/ushusadmin/dev/test_automation/servers/scriptAgentServer/node_modules/nodemailer/package.json
verbose caching /home/ushusadmin/dev/test_automation/servers/scriptAgentServer/node_modules/mustache/package.json
verbose caching /home/ushusadmin/dev/test_automation/servers/scriptAgentServer/node_modules/qs/package.json
verbose caching /home/ushusadmin/dev/test_automation/servers/scriptAgentServer/node_modules/mongodb/package.json
verbose cache add [ 'mkdirp', null ]
silly cache add: name, spec, args [ undefined, 'mkdirp', [ 'mkdirp', null ] ]
verbose parsed url { pathname: 'mkdirp', path: 'mkdirp', href: 'mkdirp' }
verbose addNamed [ 'mkdirp', '' ]
verbose addNamed [ null, '' ]
silly name, range, hasData [ 'mkdirp', '', false ]
verbose raw, before any munging mkdirp
verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './mkdirp' ]
verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: mkdirp
ERR!     at /home/ushusadmin/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
ERR!     at cb (/home/ushusadmin/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
ERR!     at Request._callback (/home/ushusadmin/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
ERR!     at Request.callback (/home/ushusadmin/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:119:22)
ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/home/ushusadmin/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:212:58)
ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/home/ushusadmin/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/main.js:412:12)
ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
ERR! You may report this log at:
ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
ERR! or email it to:
ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
ERR! 
ERR! System Linux 3.2.0-23-generic
ERR! command "node" "/home/ushusadmin/local/bin/npm" "install" "mkdirp"
ERR! cwd /home/ushusadmin/dev/test_automation/servers/scriptAgentServer
ERR! node -v v0.6.12
ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: mkdirp
verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Actually what happend is while trying to install sikuli using the comamnd removed the following items..how can i recover this items

$ sudo aptitude install sikuli-ide

```
Removing libc-ares-dev ...
Removing libc-ares2 ...
Removing libev-dev ...
Removing libev4 ...
Removing libv8-dev ...
Removing libv8-3.7.12.22 ...
Removing node-abbrev ...
Removing node-tar ...
Removing node-block-stream ...
Removing node-fstream ...
Removing node-graceful-fs ...
Removing node-inherits ...
Removing node-ini ...
Removing node-minimatch ...
Removing node-lru-cache ...
Removing node-mkdirp ...
Removing node-node-uuid ...
Removing node-nopt ...
Removing node-request ...
Removing node-rimraf ...
Removing node-semver ...
Removing node-which ...
```

Comment: Did you spell mkdirp wrong? `Error: failed to fetch from registry: kdirp`

Comment: Can you show what is in `npm-debug.log`?

Comment: sorry actually it is mkdirp

Comment: ok i will show you npm debug log please wait

Comment: hi i have updated my question with npm debug file

Comment: try again. npm doesn't work more than it does lately.

Answer (score 16):

Use the manual process to install mkdirp:

- Go to https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp/latest
- Copy the URL value of the "tarball": key
- Download the tarball
- Expand it under your node_modules path

Use the generalized pattern for the removed packages:

- Go to https://registry.npmjs.org/{module}/latest
- Copy the URL value of the "tarball": key
- Download the tarball
- Expand it under your node_modules path

As an alternative, use the npm install name@version syntax:

```
 npm install mkdirp@latest
```

Or the npm install git syntax:

```
 npm install git://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp.git
```

**References**

- [npm-install man page](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)
- [semver npm module](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/semver)
- [npm-version man page](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version)
- [npm-developers man page](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/developers)
- [npm-scripts man page](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)

Comment: Can you explain why this is necessary? I run into this error when trying to start `http-server` on one project, when `http-server` runs fine on another without this mysterious `mkdirp` in the `node_modules` folder.

Comment: @ray It looks like the `nodeVersion` parameter of the module doesn't match the version of node installed on the machine, so it can't find the a compatibile version of `mkdirp` in the NPM registry to install automatically. A [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14949118/1113772) refers to the setting the NODE_PATH environment variable. [semver](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/misc/semver.html) would be a better way, and there's also a [fix](https://github.com/npm/npm/commit/9d73de7f8a0285bfb9f4fc8f4ca1300c387fdd05) in npm-2.0 which removes redundant `mkdirp` references.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I was trying to run `npm install` from a directory where my user didn't have sufficient permissions. Take a look at those and see if that might be the issue.

Answer (score -3):

try with Yarn packaage manager , That by use of  `yarn` commmand . Its resolved this kind of issue for me