# Cannot find module 'mkdirp' while creating react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows, npm, command-prompt

While trying to create-react-app I face this error and couldn't find any fix.
[image: Command prompt displaying the error]

Solutions I have tried.

- reinstall node
- install mkdrip using 'npm install mkdir p@latest'
- npm clean cache

But nothing seems to work.

My machine setup details

- Node version LTS v12.19.0
- npm version 6.14.8
- Windows 10 x64-bit

Previously I faced no issue while creating a react app with same configurations, but now this error don't seem to go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Cannot find module 'mkdirp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625024/error-cannot-find-module-mkdirp)

Comment: I have tried this solution but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: I had the same problem with a React Native app. It was resolved after cleaning cache, removing `node_modules` folder, and reinstalling everything.