# stencil-cli installation crashes

Tags: node.js, bigcommerce

Having a hard time getting the stencil-cli installed via npm on my Ubuntu (PopOS) box. I've searched and tried a number of things (such as Node 14) but nothing seems to change the outcome.

I'm following the install guide which is [here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/installing-stencil-cli/installing-stencil) and says:

```
# Explicitly install and use supported node version
nvm install 12

nvm use 12

# Install stencil
npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli
```

Here is the error:

````
3905 verbose node v12.20.2
3906 verbose npm  v7.5.4
3907 error code 1
3908 error git dep preparation failed
3909 error command /home/patrickfranz/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.2/bin/node /home/patrickfranz/.nvm/versions/node/v12.20.2/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install --force --cache=/home/patrickfranz/.npm --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit
3910 error npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
3910 error npm ERR! code 1
3910 error npm ERR! path /home/patrickfranz/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-44c1d078
3910 error npm ERR! command failed
3910 error npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/install.js
3910 error npm ERR! internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:818
3910 error npm ERR!   throw err;
3910 error npm ERR!   ^
3910 error npm ERR!
3910 error npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'mkdirp'
3910 error npm ERR! Require stack:
3910 error npm ERR! - /home/patrickfranz/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-44c1d078/scripts/install.js
3910 error npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
3910 error npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
3910 error npm ERR!     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
3910 error npm ERR!     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
3910 error npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/patrickfranz/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-44c1d078/scripts/install.js:7:13)
3910 error npm ERR!     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
3910 error npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
3910 error npm ERR!     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
3910 error npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
3910 error npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {
3910 error npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
3910 error npm ERR!   requireStack: [
3910 error npm ERR!     '/home/patrickfranz/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-44c1d078/scripts/install.js'
3910 error npm ERR!   ]
3910 error npm ERR! }
3910 error
3910 error npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
3910 error npm ERR!     /home/patrickfranz/.npm/_logs/2021-02-19T20_34_10_706Z-debug.log
3911 verbose exit 1```
````

Comment: have you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625024/error-cannot-find-module-mkdirp#23068830

Answer (score 2):

Got it working but I'm not 100% sure what did it.

1. Manually installed mkdirp using npm. I tried the install again and it still failed.
2. uninstalled Node 12 and reinstalled it and it worked fine! :shrug:

```
npm i -g mkdirp
nvm uninstall 12
nvm install 12
npm install -g @bigcommerce/stencil-cli
```

Comment: I haven't seen that resolution for a Node project before, glad to hear you got it fixed though. Happy coding!