# Cannot install new programs with NPM on Mac

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, gulp

I'm attempting to setup a new node project with browser-sync, gulp and gulp-sass, but keep getting tons of errors. I completely uninstalled Node and NPM and then reinstalled them to no effect.

When I provide the following terminal command:

```
npm install browser-sync gulp gulp-sass --save-de
```

this is the result:

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/josephfrye/Documents/Code/Project/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:944
npm ERR!   throw err;
npm ERR!   ^
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Error: Cannot find module 'mkdirp'
npm ERR! Require stack:
npm ERR! - /Users/josephfrye/Documents/Code/Project/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:15)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:774:27)
npm ERR!     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1013:19)
npm ERR!     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:93:18)
npm ERR!     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/josephfrye/Documents/Code/Project/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js:7:11)
npm ERR!     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1109:14)
npm ERR!     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1138:10)
npm ERR!     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:989:32)
npm ERR!     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:829:14)
npm ERR!     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12) {
npm ERR!   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
npm ERR!   requireStack: [
npm ERR!     '/Users/josephfrye/Documents/Code/Project/node_modules/gulp-sass/node_modules/node-sass/scripts/install.js'
npm ERR!   ]
npm ERR! }

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/josephfrye/.npm/_logs/2021-06-16T21_19_01_116Z-debug.log
josephfrye@JosephFryesiMac Project % npm cache clean
npm ERR! As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues
npm ERR! by treating integrity mismatches as cache misses.  As a result,
npm ERR! data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid.  If you
npm ERR! want to make sure everything is consistent, use `npm cache verify`
npm ERR! instead.  Deleting the cache can only make npm go slower, and is
npm ERR! not likely to correct any problems you may be encountering!
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! On the other hand, if you're debugging an issue with the installer,
npm ERR! or race conditions that depend on the timing of writing to an empty
npm ERR! cache, you can use `npm install --cache /tmp/empty-cache` to use a
npm ERR! temporary cache instead of nuking the actual one.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you're sure you want to delete the entire cache, rerun this command
npm ERR! with --force.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/josephfrye/.npm/_logs/2021-06-16T21_28_58_342Z-debug.log
=> If you wish to uninstall them at a later point (or re-install them under your
=> `nvm` Nodes), you can remove them from the system Node as follows:

     $ nvm use system
     $ npm uninstall -g a_module
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Cannot find module 'mkdirp'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22625024/error-cannot-find-module-mkdirp)

Comment: I tried steps in your linked issue, but still isn't working. Thanks anyway.