# How to download attachment from Postman Response

Tags: postman, newman, postman-collection-runner

I have a API which sends response having following header:

```
Headers(8)
Test Results(1/1)
Status:200 OK
Time:5890 ms
Size:1.24 MB
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Cache-Control →no-cache
Content-Disposition →attachment; filename=Report.csv
Content-Length →1298149
Content-Type →text/csv
Date →Fri, 22 Jun 2018 08:50:05 GMT
Expires →-1
Pragma →no-cache
```

I want to download the attachment file 'Report.Csv'

Can anyone suggest How can I do it via script or newman

Comment: How does the attachment file is being sent by the server?

Comment: it is coming in response only

Comment: can you paste here a response maybe use «gist», it would be lovely to see how its getting to you.
Or if you can make a postman mock with the example and place it here. pls

Comment: Here is the response I am getting:

Headers(8)
Test Results(1/1)
Status:200 OK
Time:5890 ms
Size:1.24 MB
Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
Cache-Control →no-cache
Content-Disposition →attachment; filename=Report.csv
Content-Length →1298149
Content-Type →text/csv
Date →Fri, 22 Jun 2018 08:50:05 GMT
Expires →-1
Pragma →no-cache

Comment: Postman and Newman are two different tools. A specific question should be limited to a specific tool.

Answer (score 11):

If you're sending a request **from within the Postman app**, you can "Send and download" the response.

> [...you should select “Send and download”
>   which will let you save the response to your hard disk.](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/sending_and_viewing_responses/responses)

If you're trying to do it **by script**, here's [a tutorial about writing to your local file system by running a local server](http://blog.getpostman.com/2017/09/01/write-to-your-local-file-system-using-a-postman-collection/), or [how to use Newman to do something similar](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3033#issuecomment-301758179).

Comment: I tried using the script but it is not working. The Script mention uses express module. I installed express module in npm but now getting error "cannot find module 'express'". Is there a way to use send and download directly via Script

Comment: @ArchitGoyal did you install the dependences in the current directory? or perhaps your `node_modules` directory is in another place? https://stackoverflow.com/a/20142467/6815074

Comment: I installed the dependencies in the current directory only.