# How to automatically open file on download using Postman?

Tags: postman, postman-native-app

Question is self-explanatory really, I want to Postman to open the files automatically once I "Send & Download" a request that gets a file. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50984209/how-to-download-attachment-from-postman-response

Comment: @Anti_cse51 It shows how to download the response and save it in your disk, which I already know how to do. But I couldn't find anything to make it automatically open the file instead of asking to save it every time.