# Heroku -dyno stopped running/sleeping, where to add 'var port = process.env.PORT || 3000'

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm a Swift dev and not a native `Node.js` dev so I'm unfamiliar with this issue.

I signed up for `Heroku`, created an app, got the free `dyno` working and after the 450 hrs I got an email saying `Your app(s) have stopped running and will not restart until you receive more free dyno hours next month.`

I added my credit card for verification and got an [additional free 550 hrs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours). I immediately got boosted back to 1000 free hours however once I did that the `dyno` never ran again.

Just now (a week later) I ran

`heroku ps -a myAppName`

and it says I have 1000 hrs.

```
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 1000h 0m (100%)
Free dyno usage for this app: 0h 0m (0%)
```

I just ran `heroku ps:restart --app myAppName` then checked back about 15 min later and it still says I used `0h 0m (0%)`

I ran `heroku logs --app myAppName` and got these errors:

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within
>   60 seconds of launch
>
> Stopping process with SIGKILL Process exited with status 137 State
>
> changed from starting to crashed

[Heroku says](https://help.heroku.com/P1AVPANS/why-is-my-node-js-app-crashing-with-an-r10-error) to change ports and add:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Our app is running on port ${ PORT }`);
});
```

Assuming this is the reason the dynos stopped working/sleeping, it seems (I'm unfamiliar with this) I need to add the port code to my `app.js` file? **I don't know the modules to add in to get it to work.** What do I add in to get the above port code working? For eg. what is `app` in the above code?

My `procfile`:

```
worker: node ./app.js
```

My `app.js` file

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();

const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert({
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    clientEmail: process.env.FIREBASE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    privateKey: process.env.FIREBASE_PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/g, '\n'),
  }),
  databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL
});

const firebase = require('firebase');
const config = {
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    databaseURL: process.env.FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
    storageBucket: process.env.FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,GCM_SENDER_ID
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const algoliasearch = require('algoliasearch');
// rest of code ...
```

My `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "my project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Config Files",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "author": "Lance Samaria",
  "license": "ISC",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.16.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "algoliasearch": "^3.35.1",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "firebase": "^7.2.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.6.1",
    "nodejs-latest": "^1.1.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did googling around [here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/nodejs/expressjs-web-application) and [here](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2017/08/working-with-environment-variables-in-node-js.html) and found I had to install the `express` module. I used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50236578/4833705)

```
$ npm install --save express
```

Then in the top of the `app.js` file I added:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Once I installed the above code the dynos started working again. I used `5000` instead of `3000` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15693371/4833705)