# n module breaks npm

Tags: javascript, node.js, versioning, npm

After I switch from one node.js version to another with **n** module - https://github.com/visionmedia/n/, my **npm** is broken...

```
MacBook-Pro-Dmitri:~ dmitri$ npm --version

module.js:340
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'npmlog'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:362:17)
    at require (module.js:378:17)
    at /usr/local/bin/npm:19:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/bin/npm:87:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

then i'm installing npm again as it was adviced here - https://github.com/visionmedia/n/issues/101

```
curl https://npmjs.org/install.sh | sh
```

npm begins to work..

but then i do another switch for node version:

```
n 0.8.22
```

and npm now is broken again with the same error.

it's very annoying.. do I need to install npm manually after every version switch?!

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755841/how-can-i-change-the-version-of-npm-using-nvm This may help you

Comment: Also have a look on following links:
http://www.backdrifter.com/2011/02/18/using-nvm-and-npm-to-manage-node-js/
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133784/node-version-manager-nvm-npm-installing-modules-to-common-folder

Comment: What is operating system windows or ubunto?
There is windows installer

Answer (score 1):

Are there different global package repositories for different versions?

Perhaps either that package needs to be re-installed globally `sudo npm install -g` or the package manage cache cleaned `sudo npm cache clean` after switching version(s).

Answer (score 0):

Node and npm should get bundled together these days, if you are a frequent version changer like me. You can try installing node with NVM

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

This will help you differentiate packages in different node versions. Just do a npm install after the switch.

PS: The current node version is quite stable right now. You can just use the current version instead of 0.8.22

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing *npmlog* manually: `npm install -g npmlog`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and couldn’t find a solution.

It seems that [n](https://github.com/tj/n) is less well maintained than [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) so I completely removed node following [these steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11178106/1450420) and re-installed it using nvm.

(And node now includes npm)

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem on windows. I uninstalled node, deleted everything from its install directory and re-installed. After restarting command line, I got npm working again.