# Getting koa to work (nodejs web framework)

Tags: node.js, koa

I am running Deepin and trying to get koa to work. There is little documentation on the subject.

I did the following as stated on koajs.com:

```
$ npm install -g n
$ n 0.11
$ node --harmony my-koa-app.js
```

I recieve the error:

```
➜test-koa-app$ sudo node --harmony test-koa-app.js
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'koa'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/karl/nodejs/test-koa-app/test-koa-app.js:1:73)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
```

Comment: did you also remember to install koa itself? Having the harmony-enabled version of node.js only gives you the harmony-enabled version of node.js -- you'll at least want an `npm install koa` (with `--save` if you use a package.json)

Comment: Indeed via `sudo npm install -g koa`! I think my files are installed in different area though, there are no good tutorials on how to get this working :/

Comment: That's not the same. That installs it globally as executable, which doesn't do anything for koa. You need it installed locally as a code dependency, so you still need `npm install koa` for the local `node_modules` dependency (good idea to uinstall -g it again, since it won't do anything in global context)

Comment: Hmm must I include node_modules in path perhaps?

Comment: Figured it out after even more searching. Apparently the node_modules are to reside within the project directory. I always thought node_modules was included into node via a environmental. For further people look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9133784/node-version-manager-nvm-npm-installing-modules-to-common-folder

Comment: You just do `npm install koa` in your project directory. After that, any `require('koa')` instruction in your app.js will succeed. Node and npm handle the dependency chain for you - that's the very basics of how to work with node.

Comment: Karl, here is a quickstart screencast for koajs: http://knowthen.com/episode-3-koajs-quickstart-guide/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 2 of koa now out. Go here:

https://github.com/koajs/koa

Answer (score 2):

As  Mike Kamermans mentioned in the question comments, to use a module in a node application, it must first be installed in the project directory.

To install it, run `npm install koa` in a terminal in your project folder.

If you've run `npm init` and setup a `package.json` file in your project, you can add the `--save` flag and save a record of the dependency with `npm install --save koa`.